# Unable to get dynamic data into Jquery pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Not able to set dynamic data into my pie chart, please look into my code. Hard coded code is working fine but dynamic data has an issue.

```
$(contact_listddd).each(function(index, data) {
                        total_kra=data.graph_count;
                        kra_type=data.kra_type;
                        abc+= '{name: "'+kra_type+'",y: '+total_kra+'},';
                     });

var result1 = abc.substring(0, abc.length-1);

                     $('#container2').highcharts({
                            chart: {
                                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                                plotBorderWidth: null,
                                plotShadow: false,
                                type: 'pie'
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
                            },
                            tooltip: {`enter code here`
                                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                pie: {
                                    allowPointSelect: true,
                                    cursor: 'pointer',
                                    dataLabels: {
                                        enabled: false
                                    },
                                    showInLegend: true
                                }
                            },
                            series: [{
                                name: 'Brands',
                                colorByPoint: true,
                                data: [result1]
                            }]

                        });
```

If instead of result1 I hard code the data then it works fine. example below

```
series: [{
          name: 'Brands',
          colorByPoint: true,
          data: [{name: 'Firefox', y: 10.38 }, {name: 'Safari',y: 4.77}]
        }]
```

Comment: In your dynamic call what does `result1` look like? Any errors in console?

Comment: I guess your result1 is not a set of points with commas in between then - is it an array of objects? Then you should drop square brackets around result1 in `data: [result1]`. If I guessed wrong - please show exemplary result1. (A live example of your problem would be useful too - like a JSFiddle demo)

Comment: It looks like you are storing a string to result rather than an array of objects. ``abc+= '{name: "'+kra_type+'",y: '+total_kra+'},';``

Answer (score 0):

Data should contain an array of objects, so instead of storing string representation of objects, write like this:

```
var abc = [];

$(contact_listddd).each(function(index, data) {
                    total_kra=data.graph_count;
                    kra_type=data.kra_type;
                    abc.push({ name: kra_type, y: total_kra });
                 });
```

And then insert the array to the chart data

```
series: [{
  name: 'Brands',
  colorByPoint: true,
  data: abc
}]
```